# I need 2 count columns in the same query in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get the unique number of invoices a company has received and sent out using 2 count() functions. In invoices table there are two columns that are references to the same company id (one is id of a company that is sending an invoice and the other one is id of a company that is receiving an invoice)
This is the code I tried using:

```sql
SELECT K.ID,K.NAME,K.CITY, COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_INVOICES_SENT, COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_INVOICES_RECEIVED
FROM COMPANY K LEFT JOIN INVOICE F ON F.COMP_SNEDING = K.ID 
GROUP BY K.NAME,K.ID,K.CITY
```

[image: Result:]

This is for a school project so I am in no means well versed in sql/oracle

[image: SAMPLE DATA FOR INVOICE TABLE:]
[image: SAMPLE DATA FOR COMPANY TABLE:]
actual data invoices:
[image: actual data invoices:]
actual data company:
[image: actual data company:]
desired outcome with given actual data:
[image: desired outcome with given actual data:]

Comment: It would help if you posted tables' descriptions, some sample data and desired output. Although query you posted *looks OK* as far as syntax is concerned, it won't return desired result (otherwise you wouldn't be asking a question here). How are "sent" invoices distinguished from "received" ones? Also, which database do you really use? It most probably isn't MS SQL Severe AND Oracle.

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time to view the question I posted. I added some sample data with the dummy tables i created (because I don't know how to create tables here).
To answer your questions: Sent invoices are distinguished from received via CompanyID.
Database that I'm using is Oracle SQL Developer Version 21.4.2.018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; it doesn't use `count`, but `sum` with `case` expression.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  invoice (id, amount, comp_sending, comp_receiving) as
  3    (select 1, 2000 , 1, 2 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 28250, 3, 2 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 8700 , 4, 1 from dual union all
  6     select 4, 20200, 5, 3 from dual union all
  7     select 5, 21500, 3, 4 from dual
  8    ),
  9  company (id, name, city, state) as
 10    (select 1, 'Microsoft', 'Redmond'  , 'Washington' from dual union all
 11     select 2, 'Ubisoft'  , 'Paris'    , 'France'     from dual union all
 12     select 4, 'Starbucks', 'Seattle'  , 'Washington' from dual union all
 13     select 5, 'Apple'    , 'Cupertino', 'California' from dual union all
 14     select 3, 'Nvidia'   , 'Cupertino', 'California' from dual
 15    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 16  select c.id, c.name,
 17    sum(case when c.id = i.comp_sending   then 1 else 0 end) cnt_sent,
 18    sum(case when c.id = i.comp_receiving then 1 else 0 end) cnt_received
 19  from company c left join invoice i on c.id in (i.comp_sending, i.comp_receiving)
 20  group by c.id, c.name
 21  order by c.id;

        ID NAME        CNT_SENT CNT_RECEIVED
---------- --------- ---------- ------------
         1 Microsoft          1            1
         2 Ubisoft            0            2
         3 Nvidia             2            1
         4 Starbucks          1            1
         5 Apple              1            0

SQL>
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I'm guessing there's no alternative using count

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNT if you replace the 0 in the CASE expressions with NULL. So @Littlefoot's query becomes

```
select c.id, c.name,
  COUNT(case when c.id = i.comp_sending   then 1 else NULL end) cnt_sent,
  COUNT(case when c.id = i.comp_receiving then 1 else NULL end) cnt_received
from company c left join invoice i on c.id in (i.comp_sending, i.comp_receiving)
group by c.id, c.name
order by c.id;
```

This works because `COUNT` counts only those rows which have a non-NULL value in the expression which is being counted.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=47ac4b8318569be1b7406daeede1ffdf)

Comment: My friend helped to do it like this but I don't understand how it counts well. But all 3 solutions work. Thanks 

SELECT C.ID, C.NAME
(SELECT COUNT(I.COMP_SENDING) FROM INVOICE I WHERE I.COMP_SENDING = C.ID) CNT_SENT,
(SELECT COUNT(I.COMP_RECEIVING) FROM INVOICE I WHERE I.COMP_RECEIVING = C.ID) CNT_RECEIVED
FROM COMPANY C